# Summing record in table based on key in row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The table is a big table,millions of records.

Column X represents an item etc Table, chair... ...
Column Y has values which i would like to sum up.
Column Z would place the value if the row needs to be summed.

```
Table 1

ID     Column X    Column Y    Column Z   
1      X1          5           1
2      x1          4           1
3      x1          Null        0
4      x1          5           1
5      x1          Null        0
6      x2          5           1
7      x2          5           1
8      x2          Null        0
9      x3          2           1
10     x3          Null        0
11     x3          2           1
12     x4          Null        0
13     x4          Null        0
14     x5          Null        0
...  ...
the list goes on

Wanted Result
Table 1
ID     Column X    Column YY   Column Z   
1      X1          14          1
2      x1          14          1
3      x1          14          0
4      x1          14          1
5      x1          14          0
6      x2          10          1
7      x2          10          1
8      x2          10          0
9      x3          4           1
10     x3          4           0
11     x3          4           1
12     x4          0           0
13     x4          0           0
14     x5          0           0
```

I would require a select statement to get the intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
Select ID,X,Sum(Y)Over(Partition By X) AS YY,Z
 From  Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID, 
    T1.X,
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(T2.Y*T2.Z) 
        FROM 
            Table AS T2 
        WHERE 
            T2.ID = T1.ID
    ) AS YY,
    T1.Z

FROM Table AS T1
```

Answer (score 1):

is it ok for million of record than @Naveen.though @Naveen query is very short

```
with cte
(select ColumnX,sum(ColumnY) ColumnY from table1 group by ColumnX )

select a.id, a.ColumnX,b.ColumnY,a.ColumnZ from table1 a inner join cte b on a.ColumnX=b.ColumnX
```